# Eclipse Pluggable Feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have developed a RCP Application and build it by Tycho and getting below structure,

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Highlighted feature is my Custom Feature which I have implemented.
As My Custom Feature[i.e. **Feature**   **1.0.2.202008071744**] is coming under **RCP Prouct** and when I am trying to install/update the feature with **Feature 2.0.2**, I am getting below error

````
  "Feature" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Feature 2.0.2.202008071746 (com.example.p2.feature.feature.group 2.0.2.202008071746)
  Software currently installed: RCP Product 1.0.0.202008071744 (RCP Product 1.0.0.202008071744)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core 1.0.1.202008071744 (com.example.p2.core 1.0.1.202008071744)
    Core 1.0.1.202008071746 (com.example.p2.core 1.0.1.202008071746)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: RCP Product 1.0.0.202008071744 (RCP Product 1.0.0.202008071744)
    To: com.example.p2.feature.feature.group [1.0.2.202008071744]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Feature 1.0.2.202008071744 (com.example.p2.feature.feature.group 1.0.2.202008071744)
    To: com.example.p2.core [1.0.1.202008071744]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Feature 2.0.2.202008071746 (com.example.p2.feature.feature.group 2.0.2.202008071746)
    To: com.example.p2.core [1.0.1.202008071746] ```

Also when I tried to install new feature[Name - Command Version 1.0.2] it installed successfully. Once it get installed I checked it on **installation details window** its entry was not coming under **RCP -Product** and when I tried to update it, Update was successful.  Please refer below image 

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Can someone help me on below points,
1) how to perform update on existing feature/plugin wheter its is externally installed or in-built[i.e bundled with RCP product]. 
2) Is there any way by which I can include plugins which are present on some update site/locally while building it through tycho. and later as and when update is available we can perform update on it.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHjPg.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MXhh.png
````

Comment: You need to update the plug-in version (the first three parts) as well or keep the whole of the version exactly the same.

Comment: @greg-449,  can you help me on - Is there any way by which I can include plugins which are present on some update site/locally while building it through tycho. and later as and when update is available we can perform update on it.

Comment: Put them in the target platform